# Changing CSS property on entering or leaving AngularJS state

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I've got an app where I want to change a CSS property on entering/exiting angular state. My CSS property is background-color on **html** and **body** elements (basically a backdrop) which gets exposed on transitions between states. I'd like to change the color of that backdrop to make the transitions look a bit nicer. Any suggestions how I can do that in Angular?

Comment: are you using `ngRoute` or `uiRouter` for your routing?

Comment: Also my body element looks like this now:

`<body ng-style="{'background-color': getStyle()}" ng-controller="MainCtrl">`

`getStyle()` will return a variable that I was going to change on state change.. However I'm not sure that's the right approach as my `getStyle()` method gets hit *a lot* according to logs

Comment: Does it have to be the `body` element that animates?

Comment: No it's actually not the `body` element that animates, but the animating element gets `body` exposed so `body` needs to have a backdrop

Comment: So, you want `body` to have a different background *during* transitions *only*?

Comment: Exactly. Wouldn't say during - I think it should be before or after - don't really mind which.

Comment: I just posted my answer but it occurred to me: why not just have your body background colored all the time?  Does it really need to change during state transitions?

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer - it gets me further but not solving all my problems yet.. Answering your question - `body` background color needs to change because my views that I am transitioning between have different background colors. So if I'm transitioning from Red to Orange and then from Orange to Green, I can't set `body` background to just Red - it needs to be Red first, then Orange for the second transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ui-router`'s `$state` service broadcasts events on `$rootscope` as states change.  You could listen to these events and apply your style changes accordingly.  The following would cause your body to have a red background during state transitions and a white background after:

```
angular.module('myApp').run(function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
        //change body background 
        document.body.style.background = 'red';
    });
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
        //reset body background
        document.body.style.background = 'white';
    });
});
```

[`ui-router $state` docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/%24route)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It differently gets me further, however is there a way to dynamically lookup the value for `document.body.style.background` based on a value in a scope? I know I can put a custom parameter in my state to set the color - is that the right way to do it? Or do I need to set my color in the controller and lookup from the `$stateChangeStart` event?

Comment: Do you want something that will just work or do you want the 'angular way'?

Comment: The 'angular way' please :) I can hack around something that will work now with your previous answer, but would like to learn the proper way of doing it first..

Comment: You know, putting the color in the state declaration would probably be the best approach (Putting it in the controller feels like too much a mix of responsibilities).  So, in the `$stateChangeStart` listener, you would access the color value via `toState.color` or whatever

Comment: Yeah that would work I think.. So you don't think there's a way to make this a bit more dynamic? My color for the `body` will always be the same color as set on the view that I am transitioning from.. However as I understand if I put a color value inside the state, it's basically a string not a lookup, so I'll have two places where I set the same color - CSS and the state value.. I know it would work but feels a bit disjointed.

Comment: @vkislicins, it might help to add/remove a CSS class on `body` instead of applying the background color directly.  Then at least the two color declarations are in the same place.  (If you use a CSS pre-processor like LESS or SCSS, you could reduce that to one with a variable.)